# keep the selected parent menu open when a child menu is selected in Js accordian menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

when the page loads , one of the submenu of accordian is selected , so it should open the parent menu of the selected submenu  .

you can see in fiddle the 1st submenu of 1st parent menu is selcted but when it loads , it does not expand the 1st parent menu .

objective is to load menu 2  as esxpanded as the submenu 1 is already selected

check out this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/shaswatatripathy/ucgff65k/8/

--------------HTML--------------

```
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
                         <li>
                            <div class="link">Menu 2</div>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li class="active" ><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="link">Menu 3</div>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: You have a couple of problems there: (1) Include all relevant code in the question itself and do not rely on external links (2) You have marked `li` as active, but in your code you are using `a` for marking the option as active. (3) You have only coded the click handlers, so why do you expect the accordion to expand automatically. Have you written the code for that? (4) Look here and see where you went wrong -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ucgff65k/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the state of the sub items and open/show list if the one of the list item is active.

```
    if ($('#accordion .submenu li.active').length > 0 ) {
        $($('#accordion .submenu li.active')[0]).parent().show();
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xwfp6cy1/